# Book series about a group of teenagers that have powers and one boy is a dragon

Tags: story-identification, books, dragons

I read them so long ago.  Does anyone know this series?

I know it was a fairly large group of kids - maybe 5? and they end up in a different world. There's a little bit of romance between two characters, I think.

I also can't remember if it's an actual book series or I read it on wattpad.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Approximately when is "sooo long ago?"  Three months ago?  Last year?

Comment: I honestly don't have a clue - I think probably more something like 10 years ago. It's like a fever dream but I remember reading it and the plot is right there in the back of my head but I can't reach it - so annoying! I know it's not much to go on but I'm hoping it triggers a memory for someone else. I'm pretty sure it was written by a male author.

Comment: also I'm pretty sure it was written from the boy's perspective (the one who ends up being able to turn into a dragon)

Answer (score 2):

I found it! I only read the first chapter but I recognise it! It's the ***[Unwanteds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Unwanteds)*** series (2011-2016) by Lisa McMann. So not by a male author after all.

From [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/9917879-the-unwanteds):

> When Alex finds out he is Unwanted, he expects to die. That is the way of the people of Quill. Each year, all the thirteen-year-olds are labeled as Wanted, Necessary, or Unwanted. Wanteds get more schooling and train to join the Quillitary. Necessaries keep the farms running. Unwanteds are set for elimination.
> It’s hard for Alex to leave behind his twin, Aaron, a Wanted, but he makes peace with his fate—until he discovers that instead of a “death farm,” what awaits him is a magical place called Artimé. There, Alex and his fellow Unwanteds are encouraged to cultivate their creative abilities and use them magically. Everything Alex has ever known changes before his eyes, and it’s a wondrous transformation.
> But it’s a rare, unique occurrence for twins to be divided between Wanted and Unwanted, and as Alex and Aaron's bond stretches across their separation, a threat arises for the survival of Artim that will pit brother against brother in an ultimate magical battle.

Comment: Glad you found it. We'd be grateful if you'd mark your answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which is this site's way of showing that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction. You can mark an answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, however, as this is a self-answer, you'll need to wait until 48 hours after the question was first posted before the site will let you do that.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Wheel of Time, because that's the series where the Aes Sedai, Moiraine, finds a group of teenagers who might be the "Dragon Reborn." The author is Robert Jordan.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  I know there's not a lot of details in the question, but is there an element to the story that matches the teens ending up in a different world?

Comment: Hi Catherine - thank you for your reply! I checked out the description online but it's not exactly what I'm looking for. These teens/kids end up in a different world first and it's from the perspective of the boy that eventually finds out he can turn into a dragon. I think he can fly without transforming as well - that's why he doesn't find out that he is a dragon till later. They all have very ordinary english sounding names as well.